# Multiple Excel sheets to txt

Tags: python, nltk

I am new to python , and I need to perform Sentiment Analysis on multiple excel sheets in a folder.Is there any way to convert these excel sheets to txt files for sentiment analysis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xlrd](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966) to read Excel files.